# Javascript replace text doesn't render HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

With

```
<div>[[foo]] bar</div>
```

I run

```
replace(/\[\[(.*)\]\]/, function(t){return "<a href='"+t+"'>"+t+"</a>"});
```

and the page text just changes to the literal

```
<a href='[[foo]]'>[[foo]]</a> bar
```

instead of creating a working hyperlink.

So the question is, how can I get working html using the `replace` method instead of seeing a literal? Please do not recommend that I just use a linkify library -- this is just an example.

Comment: How are you *setting* the content? You are probably setting it as text instead of HTML.

Comment: Note that if you want the `.replace()` to return `"<a href='foo'>foo</a> bar"` (no square brackets) then you need to use the _second_ argument in the callback function, because the first argument is the whole match. So: `replace(/\[\[(.*)\]\]/, function(m, t){return "<a href='"+t+"'>"+t+"</a>"});`. (See that `t` is now the second argument?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why nnnnnn didn't post his comment as an answer, because it is correct. The function in `replace` accepts the matched substring as the first parameter and every other argument is "nth parenthesized submatch string" as described in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Here is the code:

```
"<div>[[foo]] bar</div>".replace(/\[\[(.*)\]\]/, function(m, t){return "<a href='"+t+"'>"+t+"</a>"})
"<div><a href='foo'>foo</a> bar</div>"
```